# Does deployment slot URL change to defined custom URL after swap to prod?

Tags: azure, swap, azure-deployment-slots

Hi I have a API deployed and is used in production, and I have been reading a bit about deployment slots. The thing is the API that is in Production has it own custom URL.

What I am wondering is that, if I deploy an updated version of the API, and swap it in Azure... would it still get the same URL as the old one?

That is will it also swap the URL, resulting in using it so that I don't have to change the URL in other connected systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not swap the custom domain names, meaning it stays in the Production slot.

The new version will be running under the custom domain name.

More info here on deployment slots: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing

> **Settings that are not swapped:**
>
> - Publishing endpoints
> - Custom Domain Names
> - SSL certificates and bindings
> - Scale settings
> - WebJobs schedulers